# How to make the text looked more clear in devdept eyeshot?

Tags: vb.net, eyeshot

When am writing text on viewport by using entity "devDept.Eyeshot.Entities.Text" , it is not cleared
and some letters are shown to be bold and some are not. I dont know why. The code for this can also
be seen below.
Thanks in advance

```
Dim TT As New devDept.Eyeshot.Entities.Text(Plane.ZX, New Point3D(xMinGlobal - Table_StartingPoint + i - 1 / 2, 0, AboveGroundElevation - 2), Title(i - 1), 0.25)
            TT.UpsideDown = True
            TT.Alignment = Text.alignmentType.MiddleCenter
            'TT.Style = "Arial"
            TT.Simplify = True
            TT.Color = Color.Black
            TT.ColorMethod = colorMethodType.byEntity

            FlatViewDisplayBlock.Entities.Add(TT)
```

[image: Text Issue]

Comment: Does setting `TT.Simplify = False` help?

Comment: @AndrewMorton No, it does not help.

Comment: Zoom in and it will help or get a 4k monitor it will also help. Your problem is half a pixel cannot be visually displayed properly on most monitors

Answer (score 2):

With eyeshot 2021 (currently, it is in Beta version) this kind of text rendering is improved.